# Any way to execute a Visual Basic designer file at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make a configurable interface to use for testing multiple devices that we make that are similar but with significant differences in command sets.  So, I wanted to be able to change the interface to the user based on which device they are testing so I don't have to create separate applications for each one.  Then it occurred to me that I could just use the X.designer.vb file that gets created when you create a new form if only I could run it at runtime to place all the controls I want and then just have a small file to help configure the hooks between controls and handler functions.  But I don't know if there's any way to directly execute the designer file.  If there isn't, I would have to make a parser myself that would read it and create the controls, but I'd rather not do that if I didn't have to.

Alternatively, if anyone knows a simple way to load a form with functions into an MDI application at runtime, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: The designer file already runs when you create an instance of the form.  It is invoked from `IntializeComponents` in `Sub New`

Comment: Yes, but only when I compile it.  I need to load a different form every time I run the application without recompiling it.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to just make multiple insteads of the form, perhaps with parameters.

Comment: @JonS: Huh? It runs as part of the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I would make multiple instances, but I only want one to be available at a time, and I want to make new instances later without recompiling the application.

Comment: No it does not execute when you compile it.  It is run from `Sub New` when you create an instance

Comment: How do I deploy it?  I need the test engineer to be able to copy a new file into the directory with the application, and when they run the application it suddenly has the new form available (or they can have a way in the application to load the new file).  They don't have Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh; you want to _re-compile changes to the file_.  You cannot easily do that without recompiling all of the source code.  Roslyn will help you a bit.

Comment: No, I don't want to re-compile changes to the file.  I want to only use the description of the placements of the controls to be able to create the form at runtime.  All the code that the controls execute won't change.

Comment: You *might* be able to read and parse the designer file, looking for element positions and, using reflection, update the controls on the form.  You would probably be better off using some kind of custom layout format though.

Comment: I definitely am able to read and parse the designer file, and it has all the layout information I want.  I'd rather not have to create my own format when there is already one existing that's useful and complete.  My only question is if something already exists to parse that format at runtime or if I do have to create my own.

Comment: Parsing designer code is still a long way from generating executable code and then executing it.  If there are a known number of form layouts as seem to be the case, just create N number of forms and show the appropriate one.  If some are similar to others, you could add/hide controls to one to make it into style 1A, 1B and 1C.

Comment: Today there are N forms, and tomorrow there will be N+1 and there's no way to know how similar it will be, and besides I would have to recompile the application to handle  the new form.  That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Put device specific controls on separate panels. (Tip at design time put the panels in different places on your form and position them over each other at runtime. Then - presuming that you can detect which device is being tested, `If DeviceBeingTested = foobar Then Panel1.BringToFront` or instead of device detection, you could change panels from a button click.

Comment: That's no different than the other design-time solutions, all of which I know how to do already, but they won't work with what I need, which is a run-time solution to handle an unknown future device without recompiling the application.